# How about mobile version specific badges for stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, badges, mobile-web, android, iphone

There are already a lot of [cool badges available at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) to engage users to be active.

..but somehow I wonder why there is none for example for having responded question at the **mobile version for the website**. Since smartphone & tablet markets are still growing I imagine that might be something that makes sense to promote!

It would also be interesting to in a user's profile the user is a mobile phone enthusiast or more a classic desktop user.

I'll list some examples here of how **mobile badges** could be, feel free to complete the list, if needed:

1. **Mobile enthusiast:** --> 30 days logged in via mobile phone
2. **Cavalry:** --> flagged first post via mobile site
3. etc..

What do you think? Maybe could also differentiate between **Android & Iphone**, but that is maybe too specific already

Comment: Maybe the subtext should read "You managed to actually be productive on a mobile device?!?"

Comment: Other than getting notifications, the mobile app doesn't do much for me.

Comment: @abhi seconded.

Comment: but there is also a mobile _website_...

Comment: I do a lot of stuff on an iPad. It's not that hard to use.

Comment: Badges indicate some sort of involvement in the network that stands out. Browsing from a mobile device is not particularly impressive.

Comment: Please take a look at the accepted answer. I think this would be the right thing to do!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel bronze badges are often used to teach users about features of the site, such as editing a post or reviewing a question or reading the "about" page.  There is nothing significant about those activities either, but they help educate.  Likewise a single badge for access via mobile might be interesting, if nothing more to show users that the mobile site (or mobile apps) exist.

Comment: I don't think having mobile versions of existing badges would be all that useful. Maybe badges only obtainable through the mobile site, maybe. But that can be easily spoofed I'd think. You can still access the mobile version of the sites from a desktop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't need to copy the badge set over and say "did this on mobile." Those would not at all be useful badges.

**At most** we could award a user a bronze badge for accessing the site for the first time from what *appears* to be a mobile device, to teach the user about the mobile website and our mobile apps. But further than that, no.

Comment: Ok, bronze badge for first access from mobile website sounds like a good idea. I think you are right that the value of other "mobile" badges would be relatively low.. sometimes I just go a bit overboard with my ideas ;-) Thanks for your constructive answer!